# Error looking up function 'pixaConvertTo8Color': when using lept4j

Tags: leptonica

I am using tess4j in Linux to use OCR in java and involved lept4j.
When using code as below

```
Pix pix = Leptonica1.pixRead(image.getPath());
```

will get the error as

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'pixaConvertTo8Color': /usr/local/lib/liblept.so.5: undefined symbol: pixaConvertTo8Color
    com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
    com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
    com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
    com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
    com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1509)
    com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1396)
    com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1156)
    net.sourceforge.lept4j.Leptonica1.<clinit>(Leptonica1.java:41)
```

I installed Leptonica from the source and got liblept.so.5 in the specified directory.

Anything special i have to take for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the lept4j version compatible with your Leptonica version.